# How to save a MS-Excel file to a USB? -C#

Tags: c#

I have an MS-Excel file that I want to transfer in my USB drive. When I click the button inside my form.

Please help me...

THANKS

**CODE:**

```
namespace usbTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //When I click this button my MS-Excel file will be transfer in my USB drive.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `File.Copy`?

Comment: I don't know how to use it. Can you teach me?

Comment: Put the following into your favourite search engine: `c# file.copy`

Comment: `Can you teach me` == complete lack of research

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Copy
(
    string sourceFileName,
    string destFileName
)
```

**Parameters**

**sourceFileNameType**: System.String - The file to copy.

**destFileNameType**: System.String - The name of the destination file. This cannot be a directory or an existing file.

```
File.Copy("sourceDir\file.xlsx","destDir\file.xlsx");
```

To get the drives for finding your USB drive, use DriveInfo.GetDrives(), show this to user and pick one. Use this drive in your destination filename parameter.

Comment: If this satisfies your question, please mark it as the answer.